# near-future tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tag-wiki

I added a [near-future](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/near-future) tag with my last question: [Low-tech inertial dampener options](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17139/low-tech-inertial-dampener-options)  I feel like this is a very common time-period to write stories on and definitely deserves a tag. However, I had a hard time coming up with a good description for the tag. I was hoping someone who is better at descriptions could help suggest a good wiki description for the tag.

In particular I feel like it should say that the world is close enough to the present day to not feel alien to present day readers. New technology will likely exist, but most of the technology should feel as simple logical progressions of the existing technology, not so advanced to be functionally magic. Spaceships may exist, but energy shields and teleporters for that ship may not. New energy generation sources could be produced, but no Singularity reached etc. However, I didn't know how to describe that coherently in so few words.

Any help on word-smithing the tag?

Comment: we already have the [tag:futurology]

Comment: @Vincent there are notable and significant differences between "near future" and "futurology". That is what OP is getting at I believe.

Comment: @Vincent I've been thinking about this and in actuality you might be right. If I had a post that I thought should be tagged as "near-future", then it's very likely I'd want it tagged "futurology" as well since they're almost the same thing. My bad.

Comment: I've updated the excerpt but not the full wiki as yet; I'm trying to come up with that now.

Comment: And I have now updated the wiki as well.

Answer (score 1):

For questions relating to the near future of humanity, featuring cultural or technological advancements that could plausibly occur within the next few decades.

I still think it's missing something, but that's all I could think of.

Comment: I'm not sure if I want to put an exact time limit.  I think that if the technology and culture feel close to our own then it has a feel of 'near future', rather that is in a decade or 70 because tech/culture stagnated etc.

Answer (score 1):

For questions concerning the immediate future, where technology is assumed to have advanced slightly while still recognizable to modern humans.

*Any extra input greatly appreciated!*

Comment: I've straight copy-pasted this into the tag wiki excerpt.